# Unix : Can't use backquote in MySQL command

Tags: mysql, unix, ubuntu

I wrote a MySQL command in bash (Ubuntu) :

```
[XXXX:~]$ mysql -h localhost -u XXXX -pXXXX -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `f-XXXX`;"
```

I need backquote in this command, cause database name is variable.

That command doesn't work and it sends `f-XXXX command not found`
I think my problem is related to backquotes. How can I do?

Comment: are you sure that `mysql some_params -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ${DB_NAME}"` is not working for you?

Comment: In UNIX the backquote ` is used for command substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not use backtick for variable substitution here.

```
[XXXX:~]$ mysql -h localhost -u XXXX -pXXXX -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ${DB};""
```

Comment: it work's too with simple quotes : I can use backtick inside simple quotes

Answer (score 0):

Bash takes the content of the backtick and runs another bash process with that as a command.

This is a backtick. **Backtick** is not a quotation sign, it has a very special meaning. Everything you type between backticks is evaluated (executed) by the shell before the main command (like chown in your examples), and the output of that execution is used by that command, just as if you'd type that output at that place in the command line.

Use $(commands) instead.

```
mysql -h localhost -u XXXX -pXXXX -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $('f-XXXX');"
```

Comment: You should cite your source: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27432/49647